# SQL find last value for multiple criterias

Tags: sql, postgresql, micronaut-data

i have a table like that:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable
(
    name          varchar(255)                NOT NULL,
    value         varchar(255)                NOT NULL,
    timestamp     TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL,
);
```

Which contains data by name, value and timestamp - obviously ;-)

I like to create a sql query for getting the last value.

For getting data by a single name its very simple

```
select * from mytable where name = :name ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1
```

But i like to have the query for a list of names.
And getting the last value for each name.

Any ideas?

Regards
Oliver

P.S using POSTGRESQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `DISTINCT ON (name)` clause in combination with an ordering clause, like

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (name)
  name,
  value,
  timestamp
FROM mytable
ORDER BY name, timestamp DESC
```